# Why does my mesh disappear when I enter Weight Paint or Vertex paint mode?

Tags: rendering, mesh, rigging

I have a problem where every time I enter Weight paint mode or Vertex paint mode, my mesh disappears; leaving the bones behind. Is there anyway to fix that?

[image: Why does this happen?]

Comment: only a guess, have you pushed [ / ] in this mode to isolate the view?

Comment: I did pressed it, it won't work, but thanks for your help!

Comment: if you pressed it try alt+h in the isolated mode to reveal if you  hid something.